# How to prevent video assets deleting from SD card after cache or junk files clere..?

Tags: android, react-redux, react-hooks, react-native

i am working on **offline video streaming app** in **react native.** i am storing all **30GB videos in sd card** locally and play in react native app. Any good way to secure that video assets. i want to prevent that video files delete anyone from that sd card. sometime after cache clean or junk files cleaner remove or delete sd card video files. so i want to prevent them for deleting anyone have little bit idea about that please help me.